# Using an IR sensor from another manufacturer

Tags: arduino-uno, ir, robotics

I am currently trying to create a line tracing robot with my Arduino Uno.

I have an IR Sensor (http://support.robotis.com/en/product/auxdevice/sensor/irsensor_manual.htm) but I am not sure if I can use this for my Arduino.

Can someone please tell me if I can? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use anything you can write code for.

Comment: Please, accept @DeanFranks answer to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to connect the sensor ADC line to an ADC input on the Arduino and calculate the range from the analogread result.  You should be able to use one of the Sharp sensor libraries, although you may need to apply a correction factor to the distance results.

Comment: Would the ADC input be the analog in bit of the arduino (i.e. A0, A1...)?

Comment: You are correct, any of the A# analog pins.